# Input string was not in the correct format : Unhandled exception

Tags: c#, formatexception

I want to calculate sum of five textboxes in 1 text box....
But when ever I remain empty one text box out of five textboxes it is giving an error
Input string was not in the correct format
 below is my code

```
        if (textBox6.Text.Length == 0)

        // textBox12.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(textBox11.Text)).ToString();
        {
            textBox11.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox7.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox8.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox9.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox10.Text)).ToString();
            textBox12.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(textBox11.Text)).ToString();
        }
        else if (textBox7.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            //textBox11.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox7.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox8.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox9.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox10.Text)).ToString();
            textBox11.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox8.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox9.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox10.Text)).ToString();
            textBox12.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(textBox11.Text)).ToString();
        }
        else if (textBox8.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            //textBox11.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox7.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox8.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox9.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox10.Text)).ToString();
            textBox11.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox7.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox9.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox10.Text)).ToString();
            textBox12.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(textBox11.Text)).ToString();
        }
        else if (textBox9.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            //textBox11.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox7.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox8.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox9.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox10.Text)).ToString();
            textBox11.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox7.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox8.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox10.Text)).ToString();
            textBox12.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(textBox11.Text)).ToString();
        }
        else if (textBox10.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            //textBox11.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox7.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox8.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox9.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox10.Text)).ToString();
            textBox11.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox7.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox8.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox9.Text)).ToString();
            textBox12.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(textBox11.Text)).ToString();

        }
        else
            textBox11.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox7.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox8.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox9.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox10.Text)).ToString();
            textBox12.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(textBox11.Text)).ToString();



       // (Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text) +
    }
```

Comment: Did you debug your code? On which line exactly? What is the value of that you want to convert? What is your `CurrentCulture`? Please be more specific.

Comment: How about telling us also what for values do you have in your textboxes?

Comment: Obviously one of your TextBoxes doesn't contain a valid integer, otherwise all the input strings would be in the correct format.  You can never trust user input to be correct if there's any possibility that it won't be.  You should use `Integer.TryParse` to validate the data as you try to convert it, which will fail gracefully and allow you to alert the user, ignore the input or whatever's approriate.

Comment: @saba awan: Why not use TryParse() and do a validation?

Comment: how? int. tryparse method ??

Comment: but if two textboxes is remain empty then it is giving this error ???

Comment: In all `if conditions`, try trimming values of text box like `if(textbox1.Text.Trim().Length==0)`

Comment: but i am handling one empty textfield... but when i remain emppty 2 textfields then same error ???

Comment: textBox11.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox7.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox8.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox9.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox10.Text)).ToString();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your code is going to get extremely messy as it goes.. I recommend you refactor..

```
List<string> texts = new List<string>{textbox1.Text, textbox2.Text};

int sum = 0;
foreach(string t in texts)
{
    int parse = 0;
    if(!int.TryParse(t, out parse))
        //Not a valid number
    sum += parse;   
}
textbox11.Text = sum.ToString();
```

You could modify this to be from a list of textboxes if you wish to tell the user which textbox is empty

---

If you are adding every textbox on the page you can just replace the list with

```
var texts = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Select(tb => tb.Text);
```

Comment: what is this list is doing?

Comment: i mean is it checking all the text boxes?

Comment: it just stores the values of all your textboxes texts, if these are the only textboxes on your form theres an even better way

Comment: where the sum can be calculted?

Comment: it is calculated - in the variable `sum`

Comment: @sabaawan - sample code for what? the code provided takes all your textboxes texts, checks if they are valid numbers, then adds them together and stores them in the variable `sum`

Answer (score 0):

try a trick as

- Check first whether textbox has value or not, if not then replace it with "0" as follows

  ```
  textBox6.Text == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Use Int.Tryparse(),when you want to get Integer from textbox.It must be something like this,

```
string text = "x";
    int num1;
    bool res = int.TryParse(text, out num1);
    if (res == false)
    {
        // String is not a number.
    }
```

Comment: but where the sum can be calculted?

Answer (score 0):

i'll like to add some points

1) Use String.IsNullorEmpty(textBox1.Text)in programming practice ,although using length is not a bad idea.

2) allow only numeric characters in textbox using properties.

3) Use trim method to fix the string before parsing it .

```
    String abc=textbox1.Text.trim();
```

4) Don't compare strings in textbox while debugging, use lengths to compare.